# Projecting to domain class with constructor with EF with AsEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

## TL;DR

Is `AsEnumerable()` on an `IQueryable()` safer to use (as in, does it already execute as `ToList()`) to have a workaround (see below) for the error `automapper Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`?

In other words **what is the effect of using `AsEnumerable()` on `IQueryable()`** especially when chaining a `Where()` to it for example.

*Please read below for full context and info*.

## Long Version

I'm implementing an abstraction for my repository layer, as I have to be able to read data from JSON files, XML files and also EntityFramework (database).

### Problem description

I was confronted when projecting my EF entities with the error `automapper Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.` when executing code like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> All() {
    return _dataContext
        .People
        .Select(p => new Person(p.Id, p.FirstName, p.LastName));                
}
```

As a reference, this is my `DbContext`, so you see that the above `_dataContext.People` returns an `IQueryable<EFPerson>`:

```
public class EFDataContext : DbContext
{       
    public IDbSet<EFPerson> People { get; set; }

    public EFDataContext() 
        : this(Settings.Default.EFDataContextConnectionString) { }
    public EFDataContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : this(() => nameOrConnectionString) { }
    public EFDataContext(Func<string> connectionStringProvider) 
        : base(connectionStringProvider()) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EFPerson>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .ToTable(Settings.Default.PeopleTable);
    }
}
```

### My solution

I didn't want to use `AutoMapper`, I also didn't want to make my domain entities have `setters` - as they needed to be immutable/read-only for the business model I'm writing.

The solution I came up with was using `.AsEnumerable()` and then project with the constructor of my domain entity:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> All() {
    return _dataContext
        .People
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(p => new Person(p.Id, p.FirstName, p.LastName));                
}
```

The code runs quick, and I can also do `.Where` projections afterwards on the domain entity. **I think this is safe** as my understanding is that `.AsEnumerable` isn't evaluated immediately like `.ToList` would be.

### Question Recap

**My Questions** thus is, is my assumption true. Is it a safe workaround to do this, or should I model it differenly - either using AutoMapper or write lengthier logic in my EntityFramework implementation of the service layer / repository?

Comment: Why don't you use `EFPerson` as your domain entity (or map `Person` to database)? You can make setters as private, EF will work with it

Comment: It is not evaluated immediately, but your next Select statement evaluates it and so brings all People from database into memory. So no, it's not "safe" in this sense. Not to mention you won't be able to update Person entities returned by that method because they are not attached to the context

Comment: @Evk writing or saving isn't needed - it's strictly read-only. Thanks for explaining though!

Comment: @Backs good suggestion, thanks. I guess I was "stuck" because my domain entities were designed to be immutable, but I guess I need to be pragmatic about it. Hence the private setters would work then I hope.

Comment: You mentioned you are going to use Where, so realize that with AsEnumerable your projection Select will bring all query into memory (just like ToList does) and your where will be executed in memory, not by database. So conceptually it is about the same as calling ToList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is quite wide, I'll describe my solution:
Use your domain entities in Entity Framework:

```
public class EFDataContext : DbContext
{       
    public IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .ToTable(Settings.Default.PeopleTable);
    }
}
```

Design your entities as you need:

```
public class Person
{
    private Person() //for EF
    {
    }
    public Person(string name) //for me
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

Query:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> All() {
    return _dataContext
        .People
        .AsEnumerable();                
}
```

Why I use `AsEnumerable` here? Just to hide my database and it's `IQueryable`.
As you can see, EF allows to work with domain objects.

Comment: Thanks, will try this asap. I was stuck in me "I need this to be immutable"- loop and thus got stuck.. Pragmatic thinking would indeed lead to private setters, thanks for cleating my stubborn mind!

Comment: Note that AsEnumerable here has exactly zero effect. You can remove it and nothing will change (at all).

Comment: @Evk for me, writing `AsEnumerable` is more explicit here

Comment: @YvesSchelpe glad to help! When I discovered it, I was very surprised too :)